# Message upon leaving a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

If I leave a Facebook group, does a notification appear in the group? (I'd like to leave a group, but don't want the other members to know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

No one is notified when a user leaves a group in Facebook. Not even the admin.

They will know only if someone looks to make sure you are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone in the group is notified. There is a notification saying what member left. I know this because I belong to a group and have left many times..as soon as I do, I receive a call from one of the members asking why, and because when someone else leaves, I can see the notification.

Answer (score 1):

There are Groups and then there are Group *Chats*.

According to the latest official documentation:

- [How do I leave a Facebook group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/172944012764072):  Members **won't** be notified if you leave.
- [Leave a group *chat* on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/187652797949395):  The other people in the conversation **will** be notified that you left.

Answer (score 0):

Although no one will be notified if you leave a public group, everyone in a (private) Message thread will see a line in the thread if you choose to leave it.

Answer (score -2):

Actually everyone in the group is notified when a member leaves.  It days. "So and so left the group".

Comment: Your answer is wrong. No one get notification even not admin.